# Journals that have “Gd” and “B’H, BS”D”, can I throw them away? Why or why not?

Tags: halacha, minhag, genizah-storage

I know that according to halacha, any notebook (etc.) which has the name of G-d written in it needs to be buried in geniza.

Does the same apply to abbreviations of G-d's name? For example, writing "Gd" B"H (for Baruch Hashem) and BS"D (for B'siyata dishmaya).

Are there sources which discuss whether these abbreviations also need to be buried?

Comment: This site doesn't answer practical questions, but rather gives sources that appertain to a question. You'd be better off rewording your question to not ask for a ruling (eg "... wondering if there are sources that speak about whether this is permitted or not").

Comment: @margotJaffe I edited the question to make it more general and in accordance with the guidelines of the group. Hopefully people will vote to re-open your question. If you feel that I changed the meaning of your question let me know and I will fix it. Thanks for sharing a good relevant question like this. Hope to see you around here again!

Comment: I don't see any problem with his question, it's a great question, please re-vote this question and not off-topic.

Comment: A rabbi once told me that inappropriate writings with the name of God (e.g., proselytizing literature) may be thrown in the trash.  I would be curious to know a source for this.

Comment: B”H
@Maurice Mizrahi - my journals aren’t inappropriate, Gd Forbid, but thank you for the information.

Comment: @MargotJaffe There is a *teshuva* in Igros Moshe on this question.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi see notes 103 and 104 [here](https://www.kof-k.org/articles/040108100403W-18%20%20Desposing%20of%20Shaimos.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Here are sources on the topic - none of which requires putting in *geniza* documents with the abbreviations you mention

- [Mishna Brura 85:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.85.10?lang=bi) **permits erasing God's name in a foreign language** - *a fortiori* then for the above abbreviations
- The Shakh ([Yoreh Deah 179:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.179.8?lang=en&p2=Siftei_Kohen_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.179.11.1&lang2=en)) holds **a name in a foreign language doesn't have sanctity**
- Kof-K, in a [broad survey of sources](https://www.kof-k.org/articles/040108100403W-18%20%20Desposing%20of%20Shaimos.pdf) notes (p. 2) "**The following does not need geniza** and one may throw items containing these names in the garbage: [...] Hashem (in English or Hebrew), B’ezras Hashem and BS’D (bais samach daled). Some are careful and did not write a BS’D on top of a letter." - see there in detail for references
- R Daniel Mann from Eretz Hemda ([here](http://www.eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=&cat=7&newsletter=4860&article=11231)) quotes "Rav Soloveitchik [...] was convinced that “**God” is not a Name**"

Of course, [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).